# get homepage from host

Tags: java, url, httpresponse, hostname

I have list of hosts and want to get homepage URL of them. The variable location that exist in   header html sometime return URL and in the most case the parameter not set.For example the URL "http://www.sharif.ir" don't have location parameter and the home page is "http://www.sharif.ir/home". How I get homepage URL from host URL ? 
Thank you

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking, but a domain should either send back the content of its "home page" if you request the domain's root (`http://www.example.com`, for instance) or it should return an HTTP 301 or 302 response telling you what the "home page" is.

Comment: You can use "http://web-sniffer.net/" address for test my example. My problem not redirection.

Comment: I want only address of "home page", not content.In my example host return content but the URL is change. How I get that's URL.

Comment: To get the address, you'll have to make a request, because the request may well be a redirect. If you get back a 200 response, you don't have to read the full response; that means it responds directly to the URL you requested. If you get back a 301 or 302, then you read the redirection information from it and try again with the updated URL.

Comment: I get 200 but the URL is changed.I want new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case seems to be a treasure hunt game. Follow the clues:

- `http://www.sharif.ir` returns HTTP 200, and the page contains an automatic html redirection (meta http-equiv=refresh) to page `/c` (`http://www.sharif.ir/c`)
- `http://www.sharif.ir/c` returns HTTP 302, which redirects to `http://www.sharif.ir/c/portal/layout`
- `http://www.sharif.ir/c/portal/layout` returns HTTP 302, which redirects to `http://www.sharif.ir/home`

Welcome to your destination ! :)

At first, tou need to parse for the meta refresh tag in the result header of the first page to get the location (content attribute : `url=<relative path>`).